# Mobile navbar not working in Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm building a website and I have to make it "mobile first". So I'm using Foundation by Zurb, because I think that it is easier.

So I have this code:

```css
/* General */

/* Header */

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { 

  .logo-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  .logo-wrapper .logo {
    width: 92px;
    height:  92px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: -2px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: -46px;
  }

  .top-bar{
   height: 150px;
  }

  // Right part
  .top-bar-section ul.right {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  
  .top-bar-section ul.right li {
    float:  left;
  }

  // Left part
  .top-bar-section ul.left {
    width:  50%;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }

  .top-bar-section ul.left li {
    float:  right;
  }
  .top-bar li{
   margin-top: 60px;
   margin-left: 25px;
   margin-right: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">

<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a class="logo show-for-small-only" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    
    <div class="logo-wrapper hide-for-small-only">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li> <a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>
  </section>
</nav>

</div><!-- /navigation -->
```

So the thing here is that, this code is perfectly working in desktop and also in mobile but when its like a medium size screen, lets say a tablet it doesn't work, it just look bad.

I can't post images for you guys to see it.

But I hope that someone can help me with that

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what the problem is on medium sized screens? A Codepen might help also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what your problem is. There's too much left and right margin within `.top-bar li` block causing some of the nav items to break out of the top bar container on medium sized screens. I've only taken a cursory look at the problem but it seems to become an issue at about the 900px mark. A quick fix for this would be adding a media query and adjusting the margin at this point:

```
.top-bar li {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) { // 56.25em = 900px 
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
  }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/thmsmtylr/pen/VvaQOr

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man! I think that it  is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with it!